# How to add multiple animations or images for 1 actor in pgzero?

Tags: python, pgzero

I have an rpg game like character that can move up, down, left, right, which uses 4 different actors each with 4 different animations. I draw items from a list, and change the list item into the actor to show the actor walking in the direction, however the animation is still running in the background, but just in a way no one can see. This method makes my game slower, is there a way to make 1 actor that can switch between multiple images or animations instead of having them in separate actors?

````
import time
import random
from pgzhelper import *

WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 720

taishan_walkspeed = 4.5

taishan_idle = Actor('taishan_idle_char1.png')


taishan_down = Actor('taishan_down_char1.png')
taishan_up = Actor('taishan_up_char1.png')
taishan_right = Actor('taishan_right_char1.png')


taishan_idle.images = ['taishan_idle_char1', 'taishan_idle_char2']
taishan_down.images = ['taishan_down_char1', 'taishan_down_char2', 'taishan_down_char3']
taishan_up.images = ['taishan_up_char1', 'taishan_up_char2', 'taishan_up_char3']
taishan_right.images = ['taishan_right_char1', 'taishan_right_char2', 'taishan_right_char3']

taishan_idle.fps = 2
taishan_down.fps = 4
taishan_up.fps = 4
taishan_right.fps = 4



taishan_player = [taishan_idle]

def idle_animation():
    taishan_player[0] = taishan_idle


def draw():
    screen.fill((172, 199, 145))
    global taishan_player
    for item in taishan_player:
        item.draw()
    
def update():
    global taishan_player
    taishan_idle.animate()
    taishan_down.animate()
    taishan_up.animate()
    taishan_right.animate()
    
    
    
    if keyboard.right: 
        taishan_up.x += taishan_walkspeed
        taishan_idle.x += taishan_walkspeed
        taishan_down.x += taishan_walkspeed
        taishan_right.x += taishan_walkspeed
        taishan_right.flip_x = False
        taishan_player[0] = taishan_right```
````

The rest of the key board movements are fairly the same

Answer (score 0):

I usually change the actor's appearance every frame.

```
def draw():
    actor = Actor(frame1)
    actor = Actor(frame2)
```